# Do a condition checking when the user shared the post on Facebook. php-api

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I made a shortcut function in `Wordpress` which is making a `Facebook share button`. My problem is that how can I know that did the user share my post?

I read some post that is using `Javascript` to get back the `Facebook response`.How can I do with my `PHP code`?

Here is my code:

```
  function add_share_button($atts, $content = null )
    {
            $atts = shortcode_atts(
                    array(
                        'url' => 'https://www.google.com.hk/',
                        'layout' => 'button'
                    ), $atts
             );

            return  '<div class = "fb-share-button" data-href="'.$atts['url'].'" data-layout="button"></div>';
    }

  add_shortcode('test_lmc', 'add_share_button');
```

Comment: You're trying to automatically click the button for the user?

Comment: No. I want to do some condition checking when the user click the button. And I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Why do you need to know when/if the user shared? Hope you are aware that you are not allowed to “reward” people for sharing in any way, shape or form, or to gate content behind it (“share this to get access to …”)

Comment: Um..I want to pop up a commercial page to the user when they shared the post. Do it not allow too?

Comment: What do you mean by “commercial page” – a simple ad? // The Share button does not return any information. You would need to use the Share or the Feed Dialog – those allow you to specify a callback function when invoked via FB.ui.

Comment: OK! thx, I am try to use `js` to do this.